# What does "The error has been consumed" mean?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I always teach my customers to tackle the first error that is reported. This is the first error that is reported when I try to deploy my web application:

> 17  persistenceUnit  WARN   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'persistenceUnit', root URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes]. **The error has been consumed.** To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

Part of the message says "The error has been consumed." What does that mean? Does that mean the error is important? Or not important?

(You'll be pleased to hear that it is not web-programming that I teach.)

Comment: The warning says that the error has been ignored (is not being reported in detail). Hopefully because it has been deemed non-important or sufficiently handled automatically. You can turn on more logging to see the details of the error.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you. I did turn on logging (I think). I got a lot more details about other things, but no more about this error. Anyway, I shall ignore it and concentrate on the next error (which I've already asked a question about).

Comment: @user7294900 Thank you for taking the time to comment. But how were you thinking the linked question would help me? (I don't intend this to be snarky, I can't even begin to understand the question or the answers.)

Comment: Maybe the next error is related.. "Load-time class transformation will not be available" certainly does not sound good.

Comment: @Thilo Googling for "Load-time class transformation will not be available" reveals [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417002/java-web-application-error-cant-find-classes-that-are-located-in-web-inf-clas) which actually suggests I can ignore it. Thank you.

Comment: maybe http://openjpa.apache.org/integration.html bottom of the page: `It is not necessary to configure a Spring loadTimeWeaver when using OpenJPA build time enhancement. The following warning message will be logged by OpenJPA when creating an EntityManagerFactory but it can be safely ignored.`

Answer (score -1):

It means the error looked delicious and the JIT compiler ate it. Think of it like how good tools swallow warnings by default. It's harmless. HTH.